# How to get date of specific day of the week in Flutter/dart?

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm writing an application in Flutter and need to get the date of the most recent Monday.
I've searched all over the web and was unable to find any solution to my problem.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-core/DateTime-class.html this link came up when I searched the web for your query. Is this it?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: @Damien Sorry, will do that next time seeing as my problem has been solved. Thanks for the tips, still quite new to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this one:

```
void main()
{
  var monday=1;
  var now = new DateTime.now();

  while(now.weekday!=monday)
  {
      now=now.subtract(new Duration(days: 1));
  }

  print('Recent monday $now');
}
```

Comment: This seemed to do it thanks! Looking at this now I could've thought about this myself hahaha

Comment: @muddassir Nice solution,Any idea to get previous two,three and so on weeks monday Date from now. subtracting 7 days is it feasible solution? But for month also need to use the logic same but we may get 28days,30days or 31days.Any idea?

Answer (score 11):

Try this one:

```
var dayOfWeek = 1;
DateTime date = DateTime.now();
var lastMonday = date.subtract(Duration(days: date.weekday - dayOfWeek)).toIso8601String();
```

With dayOfWeek being 1 for Monday, 2 for Tuesday, and so on.

Comment: Nice solution! In addition, you can use the static values already provided by dart, like DateTime.monday, DateTime.tuesday and so on.